# OLEObject available verbs for Adobe Acrobat Documents

Tags: vba, excel, createoleobject

I'm embedding a PDF in an Excel file and then using VBA to open it as follows:

```
Dim objMan As OLEObject
Set objMan = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Public").OLEObjects.Item("Doc")
objMan.Activate
```

The problem I have is that it opens it in the background and the used then needs to manually open it from the taskbar to view it. While looking for some method for an OLEObject to set focus or something, I came across the Verb Method for OLEObjects.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213649%28v=office.11%29.aspx) states that this method sends a command to the OLEObject and the available commands "are determined by the object's source application".

My question is: how do I determine what verbs are available for an Adobe Acrobat Document?

Comment: you could alternatively minimize your Excel application adding next line to your code like this: `ThisWorkbook.Application.WindowState = xlMinimized`. I don't think any verb will help in this situation. You rather need to `catch PDF window` using other techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to use the `.Activate` method on the `OLEObject`, unless there is some specific reason that you need it to be `Active` within the workbook/worksheet.  Most of the time, there is no reason to do this.

There are only two `Verbs` available for an embedded PDF `OLEObject`:

[image: PDF OleObject Verbs]

When I do `oleObj.Verb xlVerbOpen` this opens the PDF with focus on my machine (Win 7/Excel 2010).

When I do `oleObj.Verb xlVerbPrimary` this activates the PDF but does not give it focus.